# AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute 'dtype' , upgrading pandas didn't solve it

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

Im getting this error while trying to use a python library called theseus_growth

```
AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute 'dtype'
```

I faced the same error while doing the same thing on my other laptop and upgrading pandas
using this `conda install -c anaconda pandas` solved it but it this case `conda install -c anaconda pandas`  throw `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` and when I add ! it takes forever and doesn't install anything.

This is the whole error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-30b0b570169e> in <module>
      2 cohorts = [561, 670, 613, 543, 491 ]
      3 
----> 4 tiktok_DAU = my_th.project_cohorted_DAU( profile = tiktok, periods = 50, cohorts = cohorts, start_date = 1 )
      5 
      6 print( tiktok_DAU )

~\Anaconda30000\lib\site-packages\theseus_growth\__init__.py in project_cohorted_DAU(self, profile, periods, cohorts, DAU_target, DAU_target_timeline, start_date)
     95     def project_cohorted_DAU(self, profile, periods, cohorts, DAU_target=None, DAU_target_timeline=None, start_date=1):
     96         return cohort_projections.project_cohorted_DAU(
---> 97             profile, periods, cohorts, DAU_target, DAU_target_timeline, start_date
     98         )
     99 

~\Anaconda30000\lib\site-packages\theseus_growth\cohort_projections.py in project_cohorted_DAU(profile, periods, cohorts, DAU_target, DAU_target_timeline, start_date)
    231 
    232     # create the blank dataframe that will contain the forward_DAU
--> 233     forward_DAU = pd.DataFrame(columns=['cohort_date'] + dates)
    234     # build the initial forward DAU from the cohorts
    235     for cohort in cohorts:

~\Anaconda30000\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    409 ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified:
    410     Index(['value'], dtype='object')
--> 411 
    412 >>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['foo', 'bar'], 'b': [1, 2]})
    413 >>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['foo', 'baz'], 'c': [3, 4]})

~\Anaconda30000\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype)
    240                     arrays = [arr.copy() for arr in arrays]
    241                 new_mgr = ArrayManager(arrays, [mgr.axes[1], mgr.axes[0]])
--> 242             else:
    243                 array = mgr.internal_values()
    244                 if copy:

~\Anaconda30000\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py in construct_1d_arraylike_from_scalar(value, length, dtype)
   1219 def astype_array(values: ArrayLike, dtype: DtypeObj, copy: bool = False) -> ArrayLike:
   1220     """
-> 1221     Cast array (ndarray or ExtensionArray) to the new dtype.
   1222 
   1223     Parameters

AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute 'dtype'
```

What I tried so far is the following

```
!python -m pip install --upgrade pandas
!pip3 install --upgrade pandas
!C:\Users\jamit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

I'm using Anaconda navigator 1.9.6 because this library didn't work on the newer versions.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

May be you can upgrade pandas in navigator, check [anaconda documentation](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/tutorials/pandas/)